# selenium automation test script for android "toggle button"

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, nativeapplication

Can anyone please help me in writing selenium automation test script for android toggle button (eg: bluetooth, Wifi ON\OFF).
I am using Appium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetworkConnectionSetting class. Read here:

http://appium.github.io/java-client/index.html?io/appium/java_client/NetworkConnectionSetting.html

So f you have to turn wifi off just simply turn its boolean value to false.